# Use different object label for different record type

Tags: account, record-type, customlabel

we had our Account object renamed Customer. now we want to add a supplier object which is really an Account object with a different record type can do. but a record type of customer named supplier would be quite confusing.

1. can I have different object label for different record type? also I want the supplier to be able to display as a tab.
2. or is there a way to clone a standard object? I want to create Supplier and supplier contact, they are really account and contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I have different object label for different record type? also I want the supplier to be able to display as a tab.

No.

> or is there a way to clone a standard object? I want to create Supplier and supplier contact, they are really account and contact.

No.

You'll probably want to just build a new object from scratch. It's not easy to clone a standard object, and record types can't change an object's label, or create new tabs for standard objects.

Comment: T_T, I knew the answer, but just have a little hope. thank you for smashing it